# Как пройти по строке и удалить все одинаковые рядом стоящие буквы?

Tags: javascript

```js
let string = "wwsndaadowffdennn";
let strintwo = "";
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  if (string[i] !== string[i - 1]) {
    strintwo += string[i]
  }
}
console.log(strintwo);
```

Должно получиться snowden. Суть в том, что когда удаляешь сдвоенные то появляются новые сдвоенные за счёт смещения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let string = "wwsndaadowffdennn";
let stringtwo = "";
let re = /(\S)\1/g;
while (stringtwo.length !== string.length) {
  stringtwo = string;
  string = stringtwo.replace(re, '');
}

console.log(stringtwo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Запускаете цикл в обратную сторону и удаляете символы из строки, а не копируете символы в новую строку

```js
let string = "wwsndaadowffdennn";
for (var i = string.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  console.log("Index: " + i + ", currentChar: " + string[i]);
  if (string[i] == string[i - 1]) {
    string = string.slice(0, i - 1) + string.slice(i + 1);
    console.log("After remove. Index: " + i + ", currentChar: " + string[i]);
  }
}
console.log(string);
```

Если цикл запустить в прямую сторону, то получим сдвиг текущего символа

```js
let string = "wwsndaadowffdennn";
for (var i = 0; i < string.length - 1; i++) {
  console.log("Index: " + i + ", currentChar: " + string[i]);
  if (string[i] == string[i + 1]) {
    string = string.slice(0, i) + string.slice(i + 2);
    console.log("After remove. Index: " + i + ", currentChar: " + string[i]);
  }
}
console.log(string);
```

Comment: А почему в обратную?

Comment: @sinevik Чтобы при удалении символов не полз индекс текущего символа

Comment: У нас есть строка let string = "wwsnddowffdennn"; Мы вернули новую строку без двух ww. У нас теперь индекс равен s. А когда мы идём с конца, то в чём разница? ))) запутался

Comment: @sinevik Привел пример цикла с начала